# Formatting a portal in FileMaker 13 to show related text only and not keys

Tags: foreign-keys, filemaker, portal

I am using FileMaker Pro 13. I need to add **Portal** to show data from related table.
Some fields which I wanna add to **Portal** are **"Foreign keys"** from that related table that are linked-related to third table.
Results I am getting in **Portal** from those fields are numbers, but I need data (text) from that third table that is related to that **"Foreign key"**. 
Is it possible to create portal that shows text related to that foreign key, and if it is, how to achieve that?
Thanks a lot!

Example schema is on link https://www.lucidchart.com/invitations/accept/e45dfdfd-185d-46c8-ad9e-e8e8dc270ee7

In general words, I want to add **Portal** on layout based on **Table3**, so I can view related data from **Table2**, and it would have fields **tbl2item, TBL1_foreign key** (from where I pull data from **Table 1** when I enter data in **Table 2**, using pop up menu). And in **Portal** data I need **TBL1_foreign key** to be represented as text from related table instead of auto-numbers.

Comment: Please add an example or show us your code, so that we can help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the relationship:

Table 1 --> Table 2 --> Table 3

You are in the layout based on Table 1. Make sure there is relationship to Table 3 and it is in the same group (TOG) in Manage Databases. Just place the field with text from the Table 3 on your portal row and it should work.

Make sure you select the correct relationship for Table 3. In drop-down list it should be in "Related" group. Should look like "Table 3::myFiled" on the layout, with the name the same as the name of your table instance (TO) from "Manage database" which could be different from your base table name

The other option would be to use value list.

I do not see your file, so if it does not work for you, post more details about your setup.

Comment: No problem. I did not see your last edit, or would have given you more relevant example. I am glad you worked it out for yourself. Good luck!